# Trying to hide elements and call them back when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm still new to coding so maybe I'm making some rookie mistakes but here I go. In my HTML page, I have a container that is caring the only two elements I need for my javascript,  I have also added a class called "hide" in that div. I used the class "hide" to hide the contents in my CSS using display: none, so when you first open my HTML page all you see is a start button and a timer. In my javascript, I have written my code so that when they start button is clicked, the timer will go start counting down and my quiz will appear on the page. However at the moment, only my timer is working, my quiz won't appear regardless of everything I have tried. Any help will be much appreciated. Not sure if I provided everything needed but I can provide more of my code if need.

```js
const startButton = document.getElementById('Start-btn')
var funcEl = document.getElementById("func container")
startButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    clock(); 
    renderQuestion()   
});
// pos is position of where the user in the test or which question they're up to
var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, correct = 0;
var questions = [
  ["Which language is used for styling web pages?", "HTML", "JQuery", "CSS", "C"],
  ["Which is not a JavaScript Framework?", "Python Script", "JQuery","Django",  "C"], 
  ["Hyper Text Markup Language Stand For?", "XHTML","CSS", "HTML", "C"],
  ["Which languages hasn't been covered in class yet?", "JavaScript", "HTML", "React", "C"]
  ];

//   We use this functions in order to use get instead of getElement 
function get(x){
  return document.getElementById(x);
}
function renderQuestion(){
    startButton.classList.add('hide')
    funcEl.classList.remove('hide')
  test = get("test");
  if(pos >= questions.length){
    test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions correct</h2>";
    get("test_status").innerHTML = "Test completed";
    // resets the variable to allow users to restart the test
    pos = 0;
    correct = 0;
    // stops rest of renderQuestion function running when test is completed
    return false;



//Stopwatch
var c = 60;
var myTimer;
function clock() {
myTimer = setInterval(myClock, 1000);
function myClock() {
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = c--;
if (c == 0) {
clearInterval(myTimer);
}
}
}
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div id="func container" class='hide'>
          <h1 id="test_status"></h1>
          <div id="test"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="controls">
          <button id="Start-btn" class="start-btn btn" onclick="() => clock()">Start</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: share you `clock()` code please

Answer (score 1):

It seem you define duplicate onclick event.

```
<button id="Start-btn" class="start-btn btn" onclick="() => clock()">Start</button>

startButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    clock(); 
    renderQuestion()   
});
```

Please try remove `onclick="() => clock()"`.Futhermore can you share clock() fuction code ?